# Django "with" template tag renders empty for ForeignKey relationship

Tags: django, django-templates

I was using the `count` method on a queryset context variable more than once in a template, so I decided to store it in a reusable variable:

```
{% with album.photograph_set.count as numPhotos %}
    <title>My title with {{ numPhotos }} in it</title>
    <span>I use {{ numPhotos }} here, too</span>
{% endwith %}
```

The `numPhotos` variable always seems to be blank, though replacing it with `album.photograph_set.count` inline still returns the appropriate value. I also tried using the `{% with numPhotos=album.photograph_set.count %}` syntax but it exhibits the same behavior. I use the `{% with ... as ... %}` syntax elsewhere in my code and it works as expected.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check for spelling mistake or such similar errors.

Comment: Triple, quadruple checked. There are none.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this, but maybe it helps if you break down the `with` assignment. For example, first do `{% with x=album %}{{ x.photograph_set.count }}`, then `{% with x=album.photograph_set %}{{ x.count }}`. It might give some insight into what happens.

Comment: Not a bad idea, I'll try that.

Comment: It broke down after the very first attempt: `{% with album as X %}{{ X.photograph_set.count }}{% endwith %}` gives me a blank result.

Answer (score 4):

If photograph_set is the reverse relationship of a ForeignKeyField or if it's a ManyToManyField, you'll need to do

```
{% with album.photograph_set.all.count as numPhotos %}
```

Comment: That seems logical to me, but I was using `album.photography_set.count` inline before and it seemed to work. Let me try this and see what happens.

Comment: This didn't work either, exhibiting the same blank behavior as my previous attempts.

Comment: Strange, can you add your models.py to the page, along with what you're using as the context in the relevant method in views.py?